# Select all direct descendant dom elements regardless of type

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to apply CSS to any immediate child of a parent container element. How do I use CSS's descendant `<` selector to select any immediate child regardless of type (div / span / etc).

Answer (score 114, accepted):

I assume you mean the child selector.  It's `>`, not `<`.

```
.parent > *
```

That will select any element.  You can of course use any other selector as the child (an element, class, id, etc.)

Comment: And the descendant selector is the space, not "<". And an obligatory inane comment about how `*` is bad for performance, etc, as if performance matters to anyone.

Comment: @BoltClock not just bad for performance, but probably suggestive of something bad in the design

Comment: @BoltClock If performance doesn't matter to you I'd hate to use the kind of products you're building.

Answer (score 19):

If you are in SCSS then

```
.parent {
  & > * {
    
  }
}
```

Comment: Also works in LESS