# Possible to select the first child (when the first element will often be different)

Tags: css

My `div` sometimes starts with a `p` a `h2` a `h3` or an `ul`. Is there a way to select the first element of the `div`, regardless of what the element is?

Here is a JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/nv0mg602/

In the first div I would like the the first `p` to be red, not both `p`. In the second div I would like the first `h2` to be red.

Thanks everyone. I've realised that `.main:first-child` doesn't work, but `.main :first-child` does (with a space between main and the colon)

Comment: simply do `:first-child`

Comment: so do I write main:first-child { background:red; } ?

Comment: why you don't simply try and see :) you will then have the anwser

Comment: It's not doing anything!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select all direct descendant dom elements regardless of type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15302922/select-all-direct-descendant-dom-elements-regardless-of-type)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: You should really consider posting the `html` structure as well. The asterisk (`*`) is known as the **universal selector**, refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors

Comment: I've now added a link to a JSFiddle example

Comment: `.main :first-child` are the range of selectors you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `:first-child` selector with **child** item and not parent item, and since you want to consider all the childs (whataver the tags/classes are) you have to use the **universal** selector * (but it's not mandatory as you can see below).

Here is an example:

```css
.main *:first-child {
    color: red;
}
/* or simply
.main :first-child {
    color: red;
}
*/

/* or use this to select ONLY direct childs
.main > :first-child {
    color: red;
}
*/
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <p>
  Hello some type
  </p>
  <p>
  And some more
  </p>
</div>

<div class="main">
  <h2>
  A heading
  </h2>
  <p>
  And some more text
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you